# Is it possible to update OTA a rooted android device?

Tags: rooting, updates, ota-update

So my question is plain and simple, I have a Galaxy S6 with Android 6.0.1.

I want to root it but i was wondering whether this will stop me from receiving the upcoming Nougat update.

Comment: If your device is on Lollipop or newer, and you are rooted, have custom recovery, or other modifications to /system or /boot, an OTA update will likely (98% of the time) fail, the only time it wouldn't is if the OEM is dumb enough not to check for system modifications before the script runs. Attempting to update will likely put you in soft-brick condition stuck in recovery and requiring a cache wipe to get out of it. To take an OTA update you must 100% stock or it is likely to fail.

Comment: Well, why don't you root after the Nougat update?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman the update isn't out yet

Comment: @AmineBirouk Wait for the update and then root, or try your luck with the experimental systemless root.